# TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getFile' - Ionic

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, ngcordova

I have the below code to get json data and store it in a storage space in the device,I have tried the below code,

```
 ionic.Platform.ready(function() {

     $cordovaFile.createFile(cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory, 'file.txt', true)
     $ionicLoading.show();
     $http.post("http://example.com/data/get_data").
     success(function(data) {

         //console.log(data);
         $ionicLoading.hide();

         $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.applicationStorageDirectory + 'file.txt', data, {
             'append': false
         }).then(function(result) {
             alert('success');
         }, function(err) {
             // An error occured. Show a message to the user
             console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
             alert('failed');
         });

     })

     .error(function(data) {
         console.log("Request failed");
     });

 });
```

And it is showing an error in console like below :

> 4     238102   log      Error in Success callbackId: File305293268 :
>   TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getFile'
>
> 5     238107   error    Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has
>   no method 'getFile', http://192.168.2.86:8100/cordova.js, Line: 314

How to solve this?

Comment: Have you installed `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file`?

Comment: Yes,It is already installed